# ASP.Net MVC with MySql - unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider

Tags: mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, dbproviderfactories

I have installed the MySql Connector 6.6.5 from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

I have added it as a reference in my asp.net MVC website (please see screenshots below), and changed "Copy local" to true.

However, when I get to the line:`var calls = db.Calls.ToList();` I get the error:

`Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.`

I've included my code below.  Can anyone please let me know what I'm missing?

Thanks, Mark

**Controller Call.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.Entity;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using MySql.Web;
using System.Data;

namespace bm.Controllers
{
public class CallController : Controller
{
    private CallContext db = new CallContext();

    //
    // GET: /Calls/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var calls = db.Calls.ToList();
        return View(calls);
    }
  }
}
```

**CallContext.cs**

```
using bm.Models;
using System.Data.Entity;
public class CallContext : DbContext
{
    static CallContext()
    {

    }
    public CallContext()
        : base("callsConn")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<Call> Calls { get; set; }
}
```

**Web.Config Connection String:**

```
 <connectionStrings>
  <add name="callsConn" connectionString="Server=xxx;Port=3306;Database=xxxx;Uid=root;Pwd=;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
 </connectionStrings>
```

**References:**

[image: References]

Answer (score 14):

**Update**

I seem to have solved this by adding the following to my web.config:

```
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories >
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.6.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

Hope it helps someone else.

Mark

Comment: I've got a different client version I think. How do I figure out the version and publickeytoken?

Comment: I got error like "Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider.". In local pc everything works fine but when i am host to godaddy nothing is work. Please help me for solving this